# laravel-mongoDB connection issue(Windows 10)

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, php-mongodb, laravel-mongodb

I need to configure mongoDB into laravel, for that I have installed MongoDB in my machine, and also enabled PHP extension for MongoDB.
[image]

Then I wrote the following command to import the MongoDB library in laravel.
**composer require jenssegers/mongodb**
I got the following errors:
[image]

[image]

Kindly, guide me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

`jenssegers/mongodb` package is not compatible with **laravel 7.2** which you are using at the moment, now only **5.8** and **6.0** are supported.

Here is part of `composer.json` from [jenssegers/mongodb github](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/blob/master/composer.json):

[image: composer.json of jenssegers/mongodb]